# Load data from ajax request (json) on startup in AngularJs

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I have this simple page that just needs to show contents that is loaded from an external url (ajax request, response in json format)

I should say I'm a AngularJS newbie.

I've googled a bunch and found different ways of doing this and couldn't manage to determine which is the correct/simple/up-to-date way to achieve this.

My 2 challenges -

1. Making the AJAX request run on startup (I can load the page before that happens and just load the contents one the ajax request finishes. Maybe show a 'Loading..' indicator)
2. Doing a ajax request correctly.

Here is my [attempt](http://jsbin.com/oDUsuVA/1/edit?html,js,output). I know that the ajax request is never made because its not setup correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did `$http.get` instead of your `$http.jsonp` and it did work for me.

Comment: As simple as that... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are getting into .error function:
http://jsbin.com/oDUsuVA/3/edit

For jsonp your response should be something like:

```
callback([
{
    "title":"License Title 1",
    "licenseUrl":"http://cnn.com",
    "licenseText": " test"
}]);
```

Edit:
You can simply do .get() request too, but if you had to use jsonp request interface, you would have to correct response.

A [Jsonp request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) always wraps the logic into a json callback wrapper function.